# rvm throws following error while installing ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am getting the following error while installing the fresh ruby 2.0.0-p648 through rvm

```
$ rvm install 2.0.0

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rubies.travis-ci.org/ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p648.tar.bz2

Checking requirements for ubuntu.

Installing requirements for ubuntu.

Updating system..bob password required for 'apt-get --quiet --yes update': 

...........

Installing required packages: libgmp-dev....

Error running 'requirements_debian_libs_install libgmp-dev',
showing last 15 lines of /home/rank/.rvm/log/1467783851_ruby-2.0.0-p648/package_install_libgmp-dev.log
++ sudo -p '%p password required for '\''apt-get --no-install-recommends --yes install libgmp-dev'\'': ' apt-get --no-install-recommends --yes install libgmp-dev

Reading package lists...

Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgmp-dev : Depends: libgmp10 (= 2:5.0.2+dfsg-2ubuntu1) but 2:5.1.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

++ return 100

++ return 100

Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

Please help

Comment: It seems weird to me that your RVM tries to download Ruby from travisci.org

Comment: What is `rvm` version?

Comment: the version is 'rvm 1.27.0'